# I can´t build maybe this is a Kotlin bug

Tags: android, kotlin, google-location-services

I´m going trough the [stylingandroid tutorial](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/maintainable-architecture-introduction/#comments) by Mark Allison thanks.
When I run the GitHub code Sample included on that page the error is what the picture show but the code `LocationCallback` is marked red and the class cannot be resolved even do it should.

Now I created a new Android project inserted the code and you can see on the picture what happens, as the pic show, the class `LocationCallback` resolves ok but the error messages say it does not.

any ide?

here's a picture:

[image]